# Asus H61M-C Motherboard Lan

Tags: windows, lan

I Just setup an Asus H61M-C Motherboard and Lan card Onboard is impossible to Install.
OS is Windows XP with SP3, last lan driver is installed, last Bios was already updated and I already format HDD.
The thing is, even If I try to install other PCI Ethernet adapter, it fails to install also.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!
Ruben

Answer (score 0):

What does "fail to install" and "impossible to install" mean? If you want help, try to be more specific. Tell us what the error is, or, better yet, show us a print screen.

Did you also try installing the Realtek drivers located here?
http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H61MC/#support   ---> Drivers and tools ---> OS: WinXP

If you already tried it, tell us what is actually happening, because "impossible" and "fail" doesn't mean anything.